# Google Datastore -> Compare DateTime-Property with Date

Tags: datetime, servlet-filters, google-cloud-datastore

I just can't find an answer to the following problem:

I have entities in my Google App Engine Datastore which all have a property of the type "Date and time". My Datastore console shows me the format of that property. It looks like this:

> 2/16/16, 7:20 PM CET

Now I want to do a query that only gives back the entities AFTER a specific date. But how do I format that date? I tried the following:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getUpdatedEpisodes", path = "getUpdatedEpisodes")
public List<Episode> getUpdatedEpisodes(@Named("lastUpdate") String lastUpdate) {

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy, hh:mm a z");
    Date date = null;
    try{
        date =  sdf.parse(lastUpdate);
    }catch (Exception ex){

    }

    Query.Filter filter =
            new Query.FilterPredicate("lastUpdate",
                    Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN,
                    date);

    Query q = new Query("Episode").setFilter(filter);
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
```

Afterwards I try to set a new date and run this method again. I do the following:

```
repository.getInstance(context).lastUpdate = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("CET")).toString("dd/MM/yy, hh:mm a z");
```

While debugging I can see that this String looks like

> 2/16/16, 7:24 nachm. GMT+01:00

And if I try my API with this string again, I will still get all my episodes, so no filtering was done. Is this because my Date and the Google Date can't be compared if they aren't the exact same format? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by storing my date in the datastore as millis instead of date and time. This way I only have an 64-bit integer that is easy to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `String` for your date property, you can use a `Date` object:

```
import java.util.Date;
...
repository.getInstance(context).lastUpdate = new Date();
```

The Datastore will store this property so that it is sorted in chronological (or anti-chronological) order and query filters will work as expected.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types